# How display in QTreeView tree from database in Qt?

Tags: database, sqlite, qt, model, qtreeview

I use this code.

```
model  = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
model->setQuery("select id,parent,name from table");

tree = new QTreeView(this);
tree->setModel(model);
```

In TreeView displays table, but not tree. How to display tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it wouldn't return a tree as the QSqlQueryModel results in a flat table which is what comes out of the database.

You have two options for making it into a tree view, create your own model either through subclassing or just build a `QStandardItemModel`, or use an `QAbstractProxyModel` to create the mapping between your QSqlQuery table result to your grouped tree data model.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.qtforum.org/article/33291/qsqlquerymodel-and-qtreeview.html

Comment: Had the same problem and found this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/modelview.html#3-intermediate-topics